# how to show 2 elements tied together in one dropdown list

Tags: java

This works with 2 tables `userName` and `userID`.
Example: I have `id =1` and `name =x`.

I have a drop down list and it will show accordingly.

`User - [x]`

```
UserManager mgr = new UserManager();
ArrayList<User> users = mgr.retrieveAllUser();
for (User user : users)
{
    out.print(String.format("<option value=\"%s\" label=\%s\">",user.getUserID(), user.getUserName()));
    out.print(user.getUserID() + user.getUserName());
}
```

How do i make it so that it shows:

`User - [1 - x]`

^meaning i wish to get id + "-" + name, all in one option

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Please elaborate, make with examples.

Comment: I want to not only show name but both id and name

Comment: obviously it is not plain Java here. Shouldn't OP give more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html option tag is not valid, you are missing the closing tag:

```
out.print(String.format("<option value='%s'>%s - %s</option>",user.getUserID(), user.getUserID(), user.getUserName()));
```

**EDIT**

Here there are three place-holders presented by `%s`, for each place holder we are supposed to pass its value, does not matter if the value gets repeated.

`value='%s'` - user.getUserID()

`%s - %s`    - user.getUserID(), user.getUserName()

Comment: why get userID twice?